# ggplot fails to draw smooth gam using facet_wrap and group asthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, gam

I am trying to plot a multi-panel and multi-line plot using ggplot with a group aesthetic as well as `facet_wrap`. However, the `geom_smooth` fails for all lines in the facet plot when one group has too few data points.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data=df1, 
                aes(x=Year, y=Mean, group=Group2, linetype=Group2, shape=Group2)) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE, ymax=Mean+SE), width=0.2) +  
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", se=F, formula = y ~ s(x, k=3), size = 1, colour="black") + 
  geom_point(position=pd, size=2, fill="white") +  
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(min(df1$Year-0.1), max(df1$Year+0.1)), 
                     breaks=seq(min(df1$Year),max(df1$Year),5)) +  
  facet_wrap(~Group1, scales = "free", ncol=2) +  
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour="black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour="black"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.title = element_blank())
plot(plot1)
```

to produce plot the following plot. This is only summary data to make it easier. It's as if the error stops ggplot from computing the series smooths in that particular facet.

data

```
Year    Group1      Group2      Mean        SE
2011    Factor A    Factor C    30.62089116 3.672624771
2011    Factor A    Factor D    54.99066324 2.822405771
2011    Factor B    Factor C    30.48859003 3.748388489
2011    Factor B    Factor D    45.70410611 4.284244405
2017    Factor A    Factor C    33.68256601 4.030964172
2017    Factor A    Factor D    53.43496462 4.687042033
2017    Factor B    Factor C    23.08799875 5.17753488
2001    Factor A    Factor C    23.79166667 2.837795432
2001    Factor A    Factor D    23.75925926 3.688185081
2001    Factor B    Factor C    29.05555556 4.08597798
2001    Factor B    Factor D    28.13333333 7.877429079
2008    Factor A    Factor C    23.3        2.383624691
2008    Factor A    Factor D    28.83333333 2.750959429
2008    Factor B    Factor C    34.01666667 5.340999698
```

and plot

[image: plot 1]

Clearly there is enough data to draw a smooth for factorC line in group factorB. Any idea?

Comment: You just don't have enough data for a GAM. Since the lines will be straight anyway, why not use `lm`? `ggplot(data=df1, 
       aes(x=Year, y=Mean, color=Group2)) +  
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE, ymax=Mean+SE), width=0.2) +  
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) + 
    geom_point() +  
    facet_wrap(~Group1)`

Comment: Thanks Alistaire but clearly there are four points which is enough for a gam smooth, yet it fails due to the fact there are only two points in the other group. The question is why does the complete plot fail, of course it shouldn't draw a gam smooth for the two points yet it definitely should for the other group. I've also provided summary data for convenience as the data set is huge and there are many group comparisons. The issue is the fail to plot a smooth not the stats behind it!!!

Comment: You *can* create a GAM with 3 points, but as a viewer, I'm going to be *very* skeptical of any regression with so little data, particularly if it's curvy. That said, this question may generalize usefully to more reasonable cases where the smooth requires considerably more data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is rather tricky. After some testing & reading through the [current GH code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth.r) for `StatSmooth`, I've summarised my findings as follows:

## Observations

1. `geom_smooth()` fails to draw *all* smoothed lines in a plot panel, if *any* of the data groups has too few observations for `method = "gam"` **AND** `formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3)`;
2. If the plot is faceted into multiple panels, only the panel(s) with offending data groups are affected;
3. This does not happen for `formula = y ~ x` (i.e. default formula);
4. This does not happen for some other methods (e.g. `"lm"`, `"glm"`) with the default formula, but **does** occur with `method = "loess"`;
5. This does not happen if the data group has only 1 observation.

We can reproduce the above, with some simplified code:

```
# create sample data
n <- 30
set.seed(567)
df.1 <- data.frame( # there is only 1 observation for group == B
  x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n),
  group = c(rep("A", n - 1), rep("B", 1)),
  facet = sample(c("X", "Y"), size = n, replace = TRUE))    
set.seed(567)
df.2 <- data.frame( # there are 2 observations for group == B
  x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n),
  group = c(rep("A", n - 2), rep("B", 2)),
  facet = sample(c("X", "Y"), size = n, replace = TRUE))

# create base plot
p <- ggplot(df.2, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_bw()

# problem: no smoothed line at all in the entire plot
p + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))

# problem: no smoothed line in the affected panel
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))

# no problem with default formula: smoothed lines in both facet panels
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + geom_smooth(method = "gam")

# no problem with lm / glm, but problem with loess
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + geom_smooth(method = "glm")
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + geom_smooth(method = "loess")

# no problem if there's only one observation (instead of two)
p %+% df.1 + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))
p %+% df.1 + facet_wrap(~ facet) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))
```

**Explanation for observations 1 & 2:**

I believe the problem lies in the last two lines within `StatSmooth`'s `compute_group` function. The first line calls the model function (e.g. `stats::glm`, `stats::loess`, `mgcv::gam`) on data frame for each group specified by the `aes(group = ...)` mapping, while the second line calls one of the wrappers around `stats::predict()` to get the smoothed values (and confidence interval, if applicable) for the model.

```
model <- do.call(method, c(base.args, method.args))
predictdf(model, xseq, se, level)
```

When the parameters `method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3)` are used for the dataframe with only 2 observations, this is what happens:

```
model <- do.call(mgcv::gam,
                 args = list(formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3),
                             data = df.2 %>% filter(group == "B" & facet == "X")))
```

> Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
>   A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum
>   degrees of freedom

`model`, the object defined to take on the result of `do.call(...)`, hasn't even been created. The last line of code `predictdf(...)` will throw an error because `model` doesn't exist. *Without* faceting, this affects all the computations done by `StatSmooth`, and `geom_smooth()` receives no usable data to create any geom in its layer. **With** faceting, the above computations are done separately for each facet, so only the facet(s) with problematic data are affected.

**Explanation for observations 3 & 4:**

Adding on to the above, if we don't specify a formula to replace the default `y ~ x`, we will get a valid model object from `gam` / `lm` / `glm`, which can be passed to ggplot2's unexported `predictdf` function for a dataframe of prediction values:

```
model <- do.call(mgcv::gam, # or stats::lm, stats::glm
                 args = list(formula = y ~ x,
                             data = df.2 %>% filter(group == "B" & facet == "X")))

result <- ggplot2:::predictdf(
  model, 
  xseq = seq(-2, 1.5, length.out = 80), # pseudo range of x-axis values
  se = FALSE, level = 0.95) # default SE / level parameters
```

`loess` will return a valid object as well, albeit with loads of warnings. However, passing it to `predictdf` will result in an error:

```
model <- do.call(stats::loess,
                 args = list(formula = y ~ x,
                             data = df.2 %>% filter(group == "B" & facet == "X")))

result <- ggplot2:::predictdf(
  model, 
  xseq = seq(-2, 1.5, length.out = 80), # pseudo range of x-axis values
  se = FALSE, level = 0.95) # default SE / level parameters
```

> Error in predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if (is.null(newdata))
>   object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata))
>   as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)),  :    NA/NaN/Inf
>   in foreign function call (arg 5)

**Explanation for observation 5:**

`StatSmooth`'s `compute_group` function starts with the following:

```
if (length(unique(data$x)) < 2) {
      # Not enough data to perform fit
      return(data.frame())
    }
```

In other words, if there is only 1 observation in a specified group, `StatSmooth` immediately returns a blank data frame. Hence, it will never reach the subsequent parts of the code to throw any error.

## Workaround:

Having pinpointed where things were going off the tracks, we can make tweaks to the `compute_group` code (see annotated & commented out portions):

```
new.compute_group <- function(
  data, scales, method = "auto", formula = y~x, se = TRUE, n = 80, span = 0.75, 
  fullrange = FALSE, xseq = NULL, level = 0.95, method.args = list(), na.rm = FALSE) {
  if (length(unique(data$x)) < 2) return(data.frame()) 
  if (is.null(data$weight)) data$weight <- 1
  if (is.null(xseq)) {
    if (is.integer(data$x)) {
      if (fullrange) {
        xseq <- scales$x$dimension()
      } else {
        xseq <- sort(unique(data$x))
      }
    } else {
      if (fullrange) {
        range <- scales$x$dimension()
      } else {
        range <- range(data$x, na.rm = TRUE)
      }
      xseq <- seq(range[1], range[2], length.out = n)
    }
  }
  if (identical(method, "loess")) method.args$span <- span 
  if (is.character(method)) method <- match.fun(method)
  base.args <- list(quote(formula), data = quote(data), weights = quote(weight))

  # if modelling fails, return empty data frame
  # model <- do.call(method, c(base.args, method.args))
  model <- try(do.call(method, c(base.args, method.args)))
  if(inherits(model, "try-error")) return(data.frame())

  # if modelling didn't fail, but prediction returns NA,
  # also return empty data frame
  # predictdf(model, xseq, se, level)
  pred <- try(ggplot2:::predictdf(model, xseq, se, level))
  if(inherits(pred, "try-error")) return(data.frame())
  return(pred)
}
```

Define a new stat layer that uses this version:

```
# same as stat_smooth() except that it uses stat = StatSmooth2, rather 
# than StatSmooth
stat_smooth_local <- function(
  mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "smooth", position = "identity", ...,
  method = "auto", formula = y ~ x, se = TRUE, n = 80, span = 0.75,
  fullrange = FALSE, level = 0.95, method.args = list(), na.rm = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatSmooth2,
    geom = geom, position = position, show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      method = method, formula = formula, se = se, n = n,
      fullrange = fullrange, level = level, na.rm = na.rm,
      method.args = method.args, span = span, ...
    )
  )
}

# inherit from StatSmooth
StatSmooth2 <- ggproto(
  "StatSmooth2", ggplot2::StatSmooth,
  compute_group = new.compute_group
)
```

## Result:

We can run through the same cases as before, replacing `geom_smooth()` with `stat_smooth_local()`, & verify that the smoothed geom layers are visible in every case (note that some will still result in error messages):

```
# problem resolved: smoothed line for applicable group in the entire plot
p + stat_smooth_local(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))

# problem resolved: smoothed line for applicable group in the affected panel
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + 
  stat_smooth_local(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))

# still no problem with default formula
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + stat_smooth_local(method = "gam")

# still no problem with lm / glm; problem resolved for loess
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + stat_smooth_local(method = "lm")
p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + stat_smooth_local(method = "glm")
p + facet_grid(~ facet) + stat_smooth_local(method = "loess")

# still no problem if there's only one observation (instead of two)
p %+% df.1 + stat_smooth_local(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))
p %+% df.1 + facet_wrap(~ facet) + 
  stat_smooth_local(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3))

# showing one pair of contrasts here
cowplot::plot_grid(
  p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + ggtitle("Before") +
    geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3)),
  p + facet_wrap(~ facet) + ggtitle("After") +
    stat_smooth_local(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 3)),
  nrow = 2
)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to deal with this is to subset out the rows causing the problems within the data passed to `geom_smooth`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data_frame(
    Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L),
    Group1 = c("Factor A", "Factor A", "Factor B", "Factor B", "Factor A", "Factor A", "Factor B", "Factor A", "Factor A", "Factor B", "Factor B", "Factor A", "Factor A", "Factor B"),
    Group2 = c("Factor C", "Factor D", "Factor C", "Factor D", "Factor C", "Factor D", "Factor C", "Factor C", "Factor D", "Factor C", "Factor D", "Factor C", "Factor D", "Factor C"),
    Mean = c(30.62089116, 54.99066324, 30.48859003, 45.70410611, 33.68256601, 53.43496462, 23.08799875, 23.79166667, 23.75925926, 29.05555556, 28.13333333, 23.3, 28.83333333, 34.01666667),
    SE = c(3.672624771, 2.822405771, 3.748388489, 4.284244405, 4.030964172, 4.687042033, 5.17753488, 2.837795432, 3.688185081, 4.08597798, 7.877429079, 2.383624691, 2.750959429, 5.340999698)
)

ggplot(df1, aes(Year, Mean, color = Group2)) +  
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SE, ymax = Mean + SE)) +  
    geom_smooth(data = df1 %>% group_by(Group1, Group2) %>% filter(n() > 2),    # subset
                method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k=3)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~Group1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much guys for the effort. alistaire created an easy work around yet Z Lin really got unde the hood to figure out why and where it fails.